# editing pdf contents in uiwebview iphone

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ipad, pdf

hi im working on pdf manipulation.

my [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846785/how-can-i-edit-pdf-files-in-an-ios-application) are to edit the existing pdf document.

looks like there is no actual way to do it. i found out using javascript i can edit the html contents.

so now that my pdf is in uiwebview is there any way to convert pdf document to html content???

i have to do it programatically.

preferred language is objective c but its k if any suggestions in C/C++

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will have to drop down to C if you want to do this. Basically you need to get hold of a `CGPDFDocumentRef` reference, and through that iterate each `CGPDFPageRef`. From the page you can get access to the `CGPDFContentStreamRef`.

From the content stream you can parse out the primitive data that is is PDF document. From there only a good understanding of the PDF document format can help you.

I would advice you to find a commercial tool, hire an experience contractor, or change your plan. What you have your sights on is **allot** of hard work.

Comment: hi thanks for replying. i have done parsing using CGPDFContentStream but im stuck after this. i want to edit the pdf contents and resave it in the same file. there is no api provided by apple for such a thing. so is there any other way to do it???

Comment: +1 to "change your plan". What you want to do is hard. I suggest you just render the pdf and add a view on top of it where you can write your comments and highlights, then save them in a db. Then when your app opens the document again, reload the saved comments and highlights from the db.

Comment: You can also file feature requests at http://bugreport.apple.com to bring PDFKit from Mac OS X to iOS. That would make your work a bit easier, but still really hard.