# How to edit PDF Forms in iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uikit

i have a lots of PDFs forms and i want to put them on iPad and fill them up, then send it by mail. how can i edit this pdf forms in an app? i am very new with xCode and i could use lots of suggestions ...

[How can I edit PDF files in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846785/how-can-i-edit-pdf-files-in-an-ios-application)
i found this question durring my search and the idea presented here, 
"A better idea in my opinion is to create a native UI showing the data contained in the PDF file using the standard Cocoa-Touch UIKit, and create the PDF once the user is done with it so that the user can export it back. That way, you don't have to write a complicated PDF handling code." .. sounds very good just that i dont know how to start ...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what it's saying is create a nib/screen/front end to the PDF that would allow the user to record what data they want in there, then after that run a separate piece of code to write that data into the PDF!

Some links to help you out:

Quartz-2D Programming Guide (QuartzCore Framework): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html

A tutorial (Although aimed at iOS5)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

I will say, I can find information on GENERATING PDF files a lot easier/more reliably than editing them... Are the templates you have difficult? It may be worth re-creating them programatically when the data is inputted!